# Android Continuous Monitoring is being killed by the operating system

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using my Android phone as a receiver for a Bluetooth sensor located on the room. I am struggling in solving an issue, whenever I leave the phone unattended (I am sleeping), the app keeps logging information for some time but then everything is stopped and only starts working if I start the app again.

My device is a Samsung Galaxy S7, but this has happened across many manufacturers and models.

Comment: Did you manage Bluetooth connection from an Activity or from a Service?

Comment: I manage it from the Activity.

Comment: I suggest you manage Bluetooth connection from a Service to continuously run it in the background and use Android broadcasts to manage its states/events between the service and the activity or activities. Also, to conserve battery, manage the Bluetooth start/stop/connect/disconnect during app's start/close, pause/resume and orientation changes.